# Can't get security context from scheduled task

Tags: cuba-platform

I get the error

```
org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

java.lang.SecurityException: No security context bound to the current thread
```

using a **scheduled task on the core module** to execute a task once at application start:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="app_OlapService" method="initialize" fixed-rate="9223372036854775807"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I've tried both the @Authenticated annotation and authentication.begin() on injected Authentication instance.

It looks like an error triggered by the scheduling alone, **I'm also having the same error with an empty method body**.

I'm also open to alternative approaches, considering that I need to use a transaction and @PostConstruct AppContext.Listener don't allow me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are invoking a method of a service. Such invocations are intercepted and checked for the presence of a valid user session, so it should already exist at the moment of invocation. It works when a service is invoked from a client or from an already authenticated middleware code.

In your case, I would recommend extracting logic from service to a managed bean and invoke it both from service and scheduler.

As for `AppContext.Listener`, in the `applicationStarted()` method you can do whatever you want including programmatic transaction management.